# Is there an easy way to compile Go code within a Go program without reading from/writing to disk?

Tags: go, build, compilation, abstract-syntax-tree

Is there an easy way to compile Go source code within a Go program? I'm looking for essentially the same functionality as running "go build" but without ever reading from/writing to disk. The Go standard library exposes Go compiler frontend functionality (eg. via go/scanner and go/parser) that makes it trivial to generate an AST from source, but I don't see the compiler backend functionality (eg. the rest of what's handled in work.runBuild in the compiler used to compile Go standard binary distributions) exposed.

Comment: No. The go command is the interface for the compiler. However that doesn’t mean you can’t compile the code from an in-memory filesystem.

Comment: `go build` compiles not just the provided source, but all dependencies (transitively, including the stdlib) and the runtime, and links everything. It's not just "take a file and translate it to machine code".

Comment: In this case, the code has no external dependencies (other than the runtime).